# How can i implement animated and scrollable menu bar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, menu, scrollable

How I can implement the following menu (also supports scrolling and animation for bar item).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIScrollview with all the buttons as subviews. Do the animation when a button is selected.

Comment: Thanks, understood, but how about button "<<"? How I can do this layout.

Comment: I would to that as an image that is added to the scrollView. When a button is tapped, change the position and animate the change using the animation framework in UIView.